# How to run a 32 bit app on 64 bit Windows Server 2012

Tags: vb.net, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Hi I am struggling to run a 32 bit app from 64 bit Windows Server 2012. When I set it up in task scheduler it never runs. Any suggestions to the following? Thanks.

If the Application (which you are trying to schedule) is 32-bit then try launching it from the 32-bit CLI, i.e. if you want to (in this case) run

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Strate\CDReportInstall\CDReportExtracts.exe`,

tell Task Scheduler to launch:

`%systemroot%\Syswow64\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\Strate\CDReportInstall\CDReportExtracts.exe"`

This forces it to launch from the 32-bit command-prompt and hence with 32-bit emulation.

`C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c “C:\Program Files (x86)\Strate\CDReportInstall\CDReportExtracts.exe”`

When I run the above argument it says file name, directory or label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Unless there's some really unusual logic in your executable, you shouldn't need to specify a cmd.exe.  If you can double click and run it from Windows Explorer, then you should be able to run it from task scheduler the same way, as basher shows below.

Comment: Ok thanks but I cant run it from the explorer. It is not my exe its for a customer and i need to fix the problem.

Comment: When you try to run it from Explorer, what happens?  Specifically what's the error message?

Comment: It doesnt give an error message just doesnt open. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with the command line to start your application - you are using task scheduler to start it. Just point task scheduler to

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Strate\CDReportInstall\CDReportExtracts.exe"`

and you will be fine.

[image]

Comment: Ok ill try that thanks. Its not my exe its for a customer and I have to fix the problem. I also thought its stange that i have to specify cmd in the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect type of quotation marks: i.e. `“”` vs `""`

The correct type of quotation marks to use would be `""`.